# How to have multiple/several lines of window list in the GNOME 2panel?

Tags: gnome

How can I have several lines for the window list? I have to keep open many-many applications, and I need to know their name.

E.g. on Windows:

[image]

Comment: You mean Gnome 3 or 2?

Comment: I updated the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may adjust the panel size to large enough and it will split the window list to multiple rows.

Comment: yes, it worked, right click on gnome-panel, properties, then set a bigger size, works, thanks!! :)